# How do I make it so an exe file can access images and other resources?

Tags: python, exe

I am currently making a simple game with the Python module Pygame. If I were to convert it to an exe file and send it to someone else, how could I add the images to the exe so that the exe can always access them?

I've thought about just putting all of the images and the exe file into one plain folder but that's not the greatest solution since I would be sending it to a client on Fiverr who would then have to make sure the images are in the same directory as the exe etc. etc.

Comment: You have to use relative file paths.

Comment: With the most popular tools to create an .exe from Python script, you can package additional resources directly into the exe file itself, for example Pyinstaller offers `--onefile` and `--add-data`/`--add-binary` options.